# stacked butterfly chart with dual scale on spotfire

Tags: spotfire, stacked-bar-chart

I need a butterfly chart where we have 2 measurements spend and count on either side and the label being in the middle. These bars are stacked in to 2 on both the sides. I have tried creating stacked version but it is not working for dual scales. With dual scales it is coming up as side by  side bars on butterfly chart. with one  scale I am getting the stacked chart

I tried all the options but it is not working for dual scales, when i try it the chart is dying so I had to opt only the stack bar chart.

Please take a look at the chart in the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj3GW.png)